# Laravel sending custom email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail, laravel-controller

**I don't know if this is possible**

I am trying to send custom email all the users from my users table. I am using the mail fascades present in laravel.

There is a blade template like this :

```
@component('mail::message')
# New Book Lunch
 
This is the body of the email.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => $url ?? ''])
View Order
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

My method to send mail looks like this

```
class NewsLetterController extends Controller
{

    public function newsletter(Request $request)
    {
        $subject = $request->name;
        $message = $request->message;

        $email = User::pluck('email');
        Mail::to($email)->(Add my custom $message and $subject)->send(new NewsLetter());
    }


}
```

Here I want to add a custom message and subject my filling a form. How can that be done so I can add custom message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#sending-mail

You can pass the variables to the Mailable via the constructor.

```php
Mail::to($request->user())->send(new NewsLetter($subject, $message));
```

And in the Mailable:

```php
class NewsLetter extends Mailable
{
    // ...

    public function __construct(string $subject, string $message) 
    {
       $this->subject = $subject;
       $this->message = $message;
    }
}
```

If you want to pass the message to the view, your `build` could look like:

```php
class NewsLetter extends Mailable
{
    // ...

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.newsletter')
            ->with([
                'message' => $this->message,
            ]);
    }
}
```

And finally, you add the message in blade:

```php
<p>{{ $message }}</p>
```